# Wordpress multisite permalinks stop working after some time

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, buddypress

I have an annoying problem with a wordpress site and having a really hard time tracking the cause.

This is a complicated setup, using buddypress and woocommerce, with multisite enabled (only one main site), and a custom url rewriting to give each user is own subdomain.

Everything worked fine, but after some time the permalinks suddenly broke (only working using "Simple" mode with GET parameters).

Disabling all the plugins 1 by 1 changed nothing, I had to reimport the previous day database (we are still in dev so lot of backups).

Then it worked again for some days, but then broke again.
Today is the 5th time I got this bug, and I don't know what to do anymore.

I found that the bug happen when starting a network update, or saving the site network settings.

Disabling wp cron changed nothing, si I just added the AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED in wp-config, this is my last hope.

- Buddypress and Woocommerce pages are still working and correctly
  rewritten during the bug.
- Before the bug happen, I have no errors, everything is correctly rewritten : woocommerce pages, buddypress, wp pages and posts, subdomains...

If someone has any clue about this mess...

Here is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) - [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I have a BuddyPress site, not multisite though, that does this too. It seems to me that the problem occurs after a plugin update. I have a suspicion (but only a suspicion, as it's not really possible to do normal troubleshooting on this sort of random, inconsistent issue) that it's the User Role Editor plugin causing it. Like I said, I can't be sure and I'm not really pointing fingers, but it would be interesting if you too have URE installed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is interesting because that plugin is present. But it's disabled. What makes you think this one could be the cause ?

Comment: Years ago when the problem first arose I was able to do some testing and it seemed to stop with URE disabled. But since then the site is more active and I can't disable URE to do further testing. And the problem doesn't arrive on a cloned dev version of the site either, which is weird! But, I do believe it is connected to plugin updates as that is always when the permalink problem shows it's face. I've mostly gotten around it now with the little snippet (in the next comment) which flushes the permalinks after an update. I say "mostly" because it still happens now and then!

Comment: `function bgmc_plugins_update_completed( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
     if ( $options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' && isset( $options['plugins'] ) )
      flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'bgmc_plugins_update_completed', 10, 2 );`

Comment: Well it sound like a nightmare. Thanks for the snippet. We deleted URE and all unnecessary plugins, now we can just wait for it to happen again... I tried to flush the rules when the problem occurred (not in this specific hook, in init or something) but it had no effect. I'll come back if it happen again without URE.

Comment: URE might just be a red herring though, and I don't see how it can be a factor if it's disabled. The cause of your issue might not even be related to mine, but the symptoms are the same. Anyhow, I'm just glad to know I'm not alone :-)